# Data/Content Management frontend for StackMob

Tags: stackmob

For an iOS App I am looking for a BaaS provider. From a developers view StackMob is quite interesting, but I am missing a nice (web-)frontend to add and edit stored objects. The "Data Management" option in the Dashboard is unsuitable for non-technical people.

Is there a nice (free or paid) frontend for content management on StackMob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any prebuilt CMS frontend for StackMob. However, what most of our customers looking for something like that use is the HTML5 offering we have. That allows you to create a custom HTML5 app of the StackMob content that is completely your brand. It isn't as easy as the prebuilt option, but it does provide you with a lot of flexibility.

Ty